# Cassandra Java Client: AccessControlException: access denied on "C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\conf\logback.xml" "read")

Tags: java, cassandra

On Windows, using the Cassandra Java driver, I sometimes get and AccessControlException on the logback.xml file in the Cassandra install directory. I am actually using log4j, not logback.

The query works on a small data set, but fails with this or a CodecNotFoundException on a large data set.

It is likely that the AccessControlException actually masks another exception (eg timeout).

1) Why would the client want to read the logback config in the first place, and why from the install directory?

2) How can I configure a different search path for the logback config file?

The exception message:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.FunctionExecutionException: execution of 'average_by_source_1[avg_type_1, text, double]' failed: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\conf\logback.xml" "read")
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:130)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:179)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:174)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2600(RequestHandler.java:43)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:793)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:627)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1012)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:935)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:328)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:321)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:328)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:321)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:328)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:321)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:328)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:321)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1280)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:328)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:890)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:564)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:505)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:419)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:391)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by this Cassandra [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11033)

What happens is that the UDF is running in a sandbox with no file access. The logback logging framework used by Cassandra has the habit to re-read the conf/logback.xml file every now and then. If the re-read happens while Cassandra is executing the UDF one gets this random error.

Should be fixed in 3.10

As a workaround in 3.9 you can set `<configuration scan="false">` at the top of the /conf/logback.xml, no need to restart as it will pick it up on the next re-scan